# JQuery: Way to add HTML code to a div?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, tags

So I have this code

```
if ($(this).is(".item")) {
    $("#hoverdiv").text("This div has the Item class<br>Test").show();
}
```

and I have found out the hard way that using .text won't make HTML codes parse. Is there some sort of work around to this?

Comment: If you know the words jQuery, html and parse, you could have easily found it yourself. Just saying

Answer (score 2):

Use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `text`:

```
if ($(this).is(".item")){
    $("#hoverdiv").html("This div has the Item class<br>Test").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you are adding `tags` you should use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `text()`:

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
if ($(this).is(".item")){
      $("#hoverdiv").html("This div has the Item class<br>Test").show();
}
```